# HttpPostedFileBase : Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement

Tags: c#, httppostedfilebase, httppostedfile

Using ASP .Net MVC 4 Razor.

On my **view page**, I have **HTML**

```
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="multiFile" class="multi" name="multiFile" accept="jpg|png|gif|xls|xlsx|doc"/>
    </div>
```

I am using following **scripts**:

```
<script src="http://jquery-multifile-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-multifile-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.MultiFile.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In my conroller, **[HTTPPost]** method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(SampleModel model)
        {
            if(Request.Files.Count>0)
                HttpPostedFileBase uploads = Request.Files[0];

          //More codes here with model.............................
        }
```

I am following a [`codeproject`](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/531692/Multiple-File-Upload-Using-jQuery) tutorial for **Multiple File Upload** . And facing problem with `HttpPostedFileBase`. the **Error is : *Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement*.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about the error, but in the controller method you need to have the uploaded file(s) as argument(s). Which mean something like this: `public ActionResult Index(SampleModel model, HttpPostedFileBase multiFile)`. Notice that the `id` from the `HTML` should match the name of the argument in the controller method!

Comment: i have tried. but `multiFile` is `null`.

Comment: Well, in fact, it's not clear - is this a part of `Html.BeginForm` or just pure `HTML`. If the second check the `action` attribute. In fact check it anyways - do you get any data at all?

Comment: In my index action, when I debug, Request.Form["multiFile"] contains all uploaded filename. like `a.png,b.doc,c.xls`. but my Request.Files["multiFile"] still returns null.

Answer (score 0):

The Html ihave used (only added **multiple="multiple"**)

```
<div>
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="multiFile" class="multi" name="multiFile" accept="jpg|png|gif|xls|xlsx|doc"/>
</div>
```

And in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SampleModel model)
    {

        string fileName1 = "";
        HttpPostedFileBase uploads ;

        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                //uploads[i] = new HttpPostedFileBase();
                uploads = Request.Files[i];
                fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(uploads.FileName);
                uploads.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fileName1));
            }
        }
```

And I have uploaded all files!!!!